# JQuery Mobile app, make a mobile call with HTML 5

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile with Phonegap and I am trying to create a button and when I click it a phone call should be made. I have mad a lot of research for this problem and I have found the following solution

```
<a href="tel:+123456789">Call</a>
```

**or**

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('tel:+123456789', '_blank', 'location=yes');" data-role="button">Call</a>
```

This solution is working on browsers (is asking me to open Skype) but when I run it on Android with a Samsung Galaxy S2 is not working. It is not doing anything.

I have tried to add to the config.xml file the following permission:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
```

but is not working either. 
If you have any solution to suggest please do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `inappBrowser` plugin, you can launch an inappbrowser window with the `tel:` address :

```
var refcall = window.open('tel:'+phoneno, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Home,disallowoverscroll=yes');
```

you might then notice that when the call ends, you are taken back to a white screen with the tel number written on top. to avoid this, append the below code too :

```
refcall.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
                    console.log('done initiating call... closing inappbrowser module');
                    refcall.close();
                });
```

Try and let us know. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ?

```
<a rel="external" href="tel:+123456789">Call</a>
```

Comment: I have tried it and is not doing anything. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

CordovaCallNumberPlugin should help you

https://github.com/rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to `config.xml`

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
```

and use this command to dail the number:

```
window.open('tel:+123456789', '_system');
```

Comment: config.xml was already having this line. I have just added the version attribute and I have tried to open it with `window.open` but does not work either. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @AndreasH It shouId work! I suggest you to remove unnecessary lines from the config file, such as `<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />`. and check the log to capture any possible error.
BTW, it doesn't work on simulators so you need to test it on the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all the above answers you posted are correct and working fine. The problem I had, was that I was not including the cordova library in my app.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

So when I have included the above line in the header of the page the phonenumber appeared on the Dial Screen! I am using the following code to create the call button:

```
<a  rel="external" href="#" onclick="window.open('tel:+123456789', '_system');" data-role="button">Call</a>
```

I have tracked down the solution by creating a new phonegap app and use only the anchor tag given above. The cordova library was in the script by default. 
Thank you for your answers